# Operator and apparatus in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

If $L$ is an Hermitian matrix associated with an apparatus acting on state $\Psi$, how does the state vector $\Psi$ collapse or change according to matrix arithmetic?

Comment: Your language is really unclear...

Comment: How much quantum mechanics have you studied? What about linear algebra?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. The question itself lacks a proper verb (*"how do we **[verb!]** $\Psi$ collapses"*), and you should be aware that there are interpretations of QM *without collapse*.

Comment: Wave function collapse is a separate postulate. The collapse occurs when a projector acts on a state vector. These are all vectors, there are no matrices involved.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation value for an operator $\hat L$ acting on a wave $\Psi$ is:

$
\langle \Psi \vert \hat L \vert \Psi \rangle =\\
\int_\Omega [\Psi(\mathbf r)]^\dagger \hat L \Psi(\mathbf r) dV
$

(Is that what you asked?)
(Seems like a density matrix is also used for computing the expected value in more complicated quantum mechanics)

Comment: no I didn't ask for that, anyways I think got the answer to my question, just see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually while studying, I had an issue as to when should $\Psi$ collapse and when should it just modify. I now have my answers . Its basically that we say $\Psi$ collapse only if we exclude apparatus outside the quantum system, otherwise when includes, the combined system is in a bell state which upon inspection of apparatus gives the the final state- what we think of a the state $\Psi$ has collapsed to. So in  a nutshell there is no dis ambiguity on whether to collapse or just modify.

P.S question was asked by me and now i guess I have an answer.